# when i try to edit or delete it gives "trying to access property of a non object error". laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is the error i am getting when i try to delete or edit a record:

[![this is the error i am getting when i try to delete or edit a record][1]][1]

I am getting this error  when i try to update or delete a record. i have used get() method to retrieve results from query. It says when i use get() method it returns an array. However there is no problem with showing data.

**This is my controller class method.**

```
public static function deleteData($childid){
  $childid = $rss->input('hidCid');

//  DB::enableQueryLog(); // Enable query log




 DB::table('children')->where('childid', '=', $childid)->delete();
  //$del=App\Flight::find($childid);
  //$del->delete();

  //dd(DB::getQueryLog()); // Show results of log

  }
```

**in my view i have something like this.**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="tablethree">
           <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ChildName</th>
                <th>ChildDoB</th>

            </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           @foreach ( $chdata  as  $roww)

            <tr>
               <input type="hidden" name="" value="{{$roww->childid}}">
             <td> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="chx[]" value="{{ $roww-> ChildName}}"></td>
             <td> <input type="date" class="form-control" name="chxD[]" value="{{ $roww-> ChildDoB}}"> </td>
            <td>  <a href="{{ url('/moreDetails/delete') }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">Delete.{{ $roww-> childid}}</a></td>


            </tr>
           @endforeach
           </tbody>
       </table>
```

this is my whole controller class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\people;
use App\mha_dts;
use App\mha_dvs;
use App\DoTable;
use App\child;
use App\leaveData;
use App\training;
use App\Page;
use Datatables;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class jointableController extends Controller
{
  function index()
  {

   return view('join_table');
  }
  public function showTable()
    {
      $dtb = DB::table('do_tables')
      ->join('mha_dvs', 'mha_dvs.dvs_id', '=', 'do_tables.Division')
      ->join('mha_dts', 'mha_dts.id', '=', 'do_tables.District')
      ->select('do_tables.Do_id','do_tables.NameWithInitials', 'mha_dvs.division',
      'mha_dts.district','do_tables.Nic',
      'do_tables.Mobile','do_tables.PermanentAddress',
      'do_tables.created_at','do_tables.updated_at');
    return Datatables::of($dtb)

    ->addColumn('action', function ($dtb) {
                return '<a href= "moreDetails/'.$dtb->Nic.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> View More</a>';
            })

    ->editColumn('Do_id', 'MHA_DO{{$Do_id}}')
    ->make(true);

      }

  public function showind($Nic){

     $departmentData['data'] = Page::getDistrict();
    // DB::enableQueryLog(); // Enable query log






    $userss = DB::table('do_tables')
    ->leftJoin('children','children.ParentID','=','do_tables.Do_id')
    ->leftJoin('leave_datas','leave_datas.DevID','=','do_tables.Do_id')
    ->leftJoin('trainings','trainings.DoID','=','do_tables.Do_id')
    ->select('*','children.ChildName')


    ->where('do_tables.Nic',[$Nic])

    ->first();


    //->groupBy('do_tables.Do_id','leave_datas.LeaveId','children.childid','trainings.TId')

// ->select(array('*', DB::raw('COUNT(children.ChildName) as followers')))

//    dd(DB::getQueryLog()); // Show results of log


$chdata = DB::table('do_tables')
->Join('children','children.ParentID','=','do_tables.Do_id')

->select('*','children.ChildName','children.childid')


->where('do_tables.Nic',[$Nic])
->get();


$trdata = DB::table('do_tables')


->Join('trainings','trainings.DoID','=','do_tables.Do_id')
->select('*','trainings.Training_Name')


->where('do_tables.Nic',[$Nic])
->get();


$lvdata = DB::table('do_tables')

->Join('leave_datas','leave_datas.DevID','=','do_tables.Do_id')

->select('*','leave_datas.Year')


->where('do_tables.Nic',[$Nic])
->get();











     return view('moreDetails',['userss'=>$userss],compact('chdata','trdata','lvdata'))
     ->with("departmentData",$departmentData);


  }

public function store(Request $reequest){

  // $this -> validate ($reequest,[
  //   'mchname' => 'required',
  //   'mdob' => 'required',
  //
  // ]);

  $chs = new child ;

  $chs -> ChildName = $reequest->input('mchname');
  $chs -> ChildDoB =$reequest->input('mdob');
  $chs -> ParentID = $reequest->input('mchdoid');


$chs->save();
return redirect()
->back()
-> with ('success','data saved!');


}
public function update(Request $editreq)
{
//DB::enableQueryLog(); // Enable query log
     $Do_id = $editreq->input('ddoid');


  $editDo =  DoTable::find($Do_id);


  $editDo-> District=  $editreq->input('District');
  $editDo-> Division=  $editreq->input('Division');
  $editDo-> Full_Name=  $editreq->input('fname');
  $editDo-> NameWithInitials=  $editreq->input('inName');
  $editDo-> Nic=  $editreq->input('nic');
  $editDo-> DoB=  $editreq->input('dob');
  $editDo-> Mobile=  $editreq->input('mobile');
  $editDo-> Landline=  $editreq->input('land');
  $editDo-> PermanentAddress=  $editreq->input('paddress');
  $editDo-> CurrentAddress=  $editreq->input('caddress');
  $editDo-> SpouseName=  $editreq->input('spname');
  $editDo-> Designation=  $editreq->input('designation');
  $editDo-> Workstation=  $editreq->input('wstation');

  $editDo-> CurrentServiceLocation=  $editreq->input('workstation');
  $editDo-> FromDate=  $editreq->input('fromdate');
  $editDo-> ToDate=  $editreq->input('todate');
  $editDo-> Ministry=  $editreq->input('ministry');
  $editDo-> Degree=  $editreq->input('degree');
  $editDo-> Subject=  $editreq->input('sarea');
  $editDo-> Institiute=  $editreq->input('institute');


  $editDo-> AppointmentLetterNum=  $editreq->input('Aletter');
  $editDo-> AppointmentDate=  $editreq->input('Apdate');
  $editDo-> AbsorbedLetterNum=  $editreq->input('abletter');
  $editDo-> AbsorbedDate=  $editreq->input('abdate');
  $editDo-> PermenentDate=  $editreq->input('perdate');
  $editDo-> LanguageProf=  $editreq->input('optradio');
  $editDo-> PassedDate=  $editreq->input('passdate');
  $editDo-> SalaryIncrement=  $editreq->input('lastinc');

  $editDo-> IncrementedDate=  $editreq->input('incDate');
  $editDo-> WOPNum=  $editreq->input('WOPNum');
  $editDo-> NumOfDepends=  $editreq->input('NoDep');
  $editDo-> OtherDetails=  $editreq->input('otherd');
  $editDo->save();
  //dd(DB::getQueryLog()); // Show results of log

  return redirect()
  ->back();


}
public function childUpdate(Request $rss){
    $childid = $rss->input('hidCid');
 //DB::enableQueryLog(); // Enable query log

  $editchild = child::findOrFail($childid);

//dd(DB::getQueryLog()); // Show results of log
  $cname = $rss -> input('chx');
  $cdob = $rss-> input('chxD');

  for ($i=0; $i < count($cname) ; $i++) {
    $cdata  = array(

      'ChildName' =>  $cname[$i] ,
       'ChildDoB'  =>  $cdob[$i] );

       $updateData[]=$cdata;

  }
  child::update($updateData);

  // $editchild-> ChildName = $rss -> input('chx');
  // $editchild-> ChildDoB = $rss -> input('chxD');
  // $editchild->save();
  return redirect()
  ->back();





}
public static function deleteData($childid){
  $childid = $rss->input('hidCid');

//  DB::enableQueryLog(); // Enable query log




 DB::table('children')->where('childid', '=', $childid)->delete();
  //$del=App\Flight::find($childid);
  //$del->delete();

  //dd(DB::getQueryLog()); // Show results of log

  }
```

Comment: Welcome in stackoverflow..

Comment: `$childid = $rss->input('hidCid');` Why do you reassign `$childid` and where is `$rss` set? And `<input>` inside `<tr>` is not valid

Comment: @lagbox  yes, that's my view. i'm returning the view from a route .

Comment: Route::get('/moreDetails/delete',['uses'=>'jointableController@deleteData', 'as'=>'/moreDetails/delete']);                     laravel 5.8

Comment: you are not returning any view from the method you have provided in your question, provide your actual code

Comment: i have put the whole controller. I just want to delete a record.

Comment: the image of the stack trace is gone now, you need to open the file the error is talking about and go to the line it is talking about and see what is happening on that line, that is how stack traces work ... your delete method has nothing to do with the error you are getting, it is coming form the view

Comment: yes i know, i tried many things. The problem is as i think, i'm getting an array as a result of the query (by get()) do you know how can i access an array inside the view?

Comment: in Laravel 5.8 Query Builder returns a Collection of stdClass objects, no arrays ... paste the exact line that the error is talking about

Comment: it says "3c9b49ac6458f67bf08aadd8883b57a120d24652.php line 33" but i don't know what is that php file.  Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\blog\resources\views\moreDetails.blade.php) and this too.

Comment: found the line  <?php $old= $userss-> District; ?>  doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: because when you are guessing it is hard to know what is causing the error so you have provided the part of the view that isn't actually relevant to the error ... this is why using the stacktrace is so important so you hopefully find the exact line that is causing the error instead of guessing ;-)

Comment: i understand, but i still can't fix the error. here is the scenario. There are two tables DOTable and children. One DO has many children. I'm only deleting children. That has nothing to do with District attribute.

Comment: this error has nothing to do with the delete method ... again .. this in that view file, what you want to do in the rest of your application is irrelevant to the error your question is about

Comment: once you resolve this error, you will then face other errors, but you will most likely have to create a separate question for them ... just make sure to keep everything as simple as possible and provide the relevant code that goes along with any errors and you will get help fast and people will have no problem helping out, best of luck with your project

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you passing any request object? If you have source controller then you need to pass data as form data with delete method.
route file

```
Route::resource('crud','CrudsController');
```

view file

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('crud.destroy',$row->id)}}">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')               
                <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
            </form>
```

in your controller

```
 public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
        $data=Crud::findOrFail($id);
        $data->delete();
        return redirect('crud')->with('success','Data is deleted successfully');
    }
```

Comment: glad to help you.

Answer (score -1):

The query you use to get `$userss` uses `first()`, which can return a single record or `null`. `$userss` is `null` and in the view it is being accessed as `$userss->District`. Which is `null->District` which would cause the error "Trying to access property of a non object".

You are not deleting anything. This is your view to show the page, not delete any records. You are trying to use the `$userss` variable in your view and you are not showing your view so no one could possible know what you are actually trying to do. You will need to check if `$userss` is `null` or not before you use it.

It is up to you now to decide how you want to handle dealing with the logic of this `$userss` variable potentially being `null`.